# Excel Equation to determine if every value in one range has a match with a value in another range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

As a completeness check for the user of a financial model, I need an equation that will tell if every product heirarchy has been accounted for.  This means every value in range B1:B100 on Tab1 should be accounted for in range C2:c200 on Tab2.  If this condition is met, the formula should say "Complete", if not "Incomplete".  Anyone aware of how to create a function like this?

```
=if(Every value in tab1!b1:b100 has a match in tab2!c2:c200, "Complete", "Incomplete")
```

Comment: How do you feel about VBA?  This might be a quick Macro or User Defined Function (UDF).  Also might be needlessly difficult to do on the formula bar, but Data Validation rules might help in that regard.

Comment: I'm somewhat comfortable with VBA however I'm unaware how to create a Macro of this nature

Comment: Would you want "Complete" or "Incomplete" to be placed in an adjacent column to B##? or would you like an alert box when the sub is finished saying complete if they are all present and incomplete if 1 or more is not?  (Do you want to know which ones are missing and which ones are found?) -- Also important: Are the ranges always going to be the same B1:B100 and C2:C200?  as well as the tab names or tab location in the workbook (1, 2)?  This is very doable, but accounting for potential changes in format is where good programming comes in.

Comment: I would just like one box on the side of the sheet, sitting at the top of column M that has a big green complete or a big red incomplete so the user can easily see if they haven't updated properly

Comment: Wookies, thanks for the help, Gary's students equation worked perfectly for what I needed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well to **count** the number of matches, we can use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Sheet1!B1:B100,Sheet2!C2:C200))
```

To test if everything in the first sheet can be found in the second sheet:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Sheet1!B1:B100,Sheet2!C2:C200)) = COUNTA(Sheet1!B1:B100)
```

or

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(Sheet1!B1:B100,Sheet2!C2:C200)) = 100
```

if there are no blanks or dups.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly well when combined with an If statement,  Much appreciated!

Comment: @oryan5000  You are quite welcome! .................you gotta love `SUMPRODUCT()`

Comment: Clever and straight forward - WWC

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code  It is pretty neat, but if there are duplicated values **within** one of the columns, all bets are off.

Comment: I was mashing up running each B value versus every C (nested For) with a Boolean break at the first "Not Found" into Incomplete, if you don't break then you know you reached a a complete status. But . .  other answers came in faster.

Answer (score 1):

just to add a VBA solution

```
Sub columnsMatch()
    Dim filters As Variant
    filters = Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C2:C200").Value)

    With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("b1:b100") 'reference "Sheet1" sheet range B1:B100
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=filters, Operator:=xlFilterValues ' filter referenced range with values from "Sheet2" sheet range C2:C200
        .Parent.Range("M1").Value = IIf(Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) = .Count And Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(1, 1).Value, filters, 0)), "Complete", "Incomplete")
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False ' remove filters
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: hoping the brave down voter supply any savy advice to enhance my answer

Comment: you are welcome. while... there seem to be some shy guy not appreciating it

Comment: he/she must be veeeery lonely